# How do I get a reference to ARCGISRuntime SystemLocationDataSource in .net Standard Library?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, arcgis-runtime

I have an .net Xamarin Map app using Ersi ARCGIS mapping that I created using a .net Standard class library for all my shared code, Xamarin forms. How do i get a reference to a SystemLocationDataSouce that is only available in the specific android or IOS project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. For Android you need to call CheckSelfPermission() and RequestPermissions() in your android activity. You can do this in your library project like this. Here I'm passing in a reference to my map control so I can set the location source property from Android. Examples of this can be found in Ersi ARCGIS sample code.

```
#if XAMARIN_ANDROID
                // See implementation in MainActivity.cs in the Android platform project.
                MainActivity.Instance.AskForLocationPermission(MyMapView);
#else
                await MyMapView.LocationDisplay.DataSource.StartAsync();
                MyMapView.LocationDisplay.IsEnabled = true;
#endif
```